# Conditional Completable in RxJava2

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I often find myself creating streams which depend on some condition provided by a `Single<Boolean>`. Consider this example:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.range(0, 10)
            .flatMapSingle(this::shouldDoStuff)
            .flatMapCompletable(shouldDoStuff -> shouldDoStuff ? doStuff() : Completable.complete())
            .test();
}

private Single<Boolean> shouldDoStuff(int number) {
    return Single.just(number % 2 == 0);
}

private Completable doStuff() {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("Did stuff"));
}
```

I find the `flatMapSingle(...).flatMapCompletable(...)` part to be unnecessary verbose.

Maybe there are operators available that could simplify this, e.g.:

```java
Observable.range(0, 10)
        .flatMapSingle(this::shouldDoStuff)
        .flatMapCompletableIfTrue(doStuff())
        .test();
```

Or a static constructor that wraps the two lines, e.g.:

```java
Observable.range(0, 10)
        .flatMapCompletable(number -> Completable.ifTrue(shouldDoStuff(number), doStuff()))
        .test();
```

Please let me know how you would implement this if this kind of condition check would be part of many of your streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `filter` operator on the result of `shouldDoStuff`

```
 Observable.range(0, 10)
            .flatMapSingle(this::shouldDoStuff)
            .filter(shouldDo -> shouldDo)  // this will emit to the downstream only if shouldDo = true
            .flatMapCompletable(__ -> doStuff())
            .test();
```

Or try writing a wrapper to make the code more readable, (by moving your same logic to wrapper )

```
  class CompletableIfTrue {
    public static CompletableSource when(Single<Boolean> shouldDoStuff, Completable doStuff) {
        return shouldDoStuff.flatMapCompletable(shouldDo -> shouldDo ? doStuff : Completable.complete());
    }
```

And

```
Observable.range(0, 10)
     .flatMapCompletable(number -> CompletableIfTrue.when(shouldDoStuff(number), doStuff()))
     .test();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the `filter` approach is even more verbose. In addition, it prevents events from going downstream. I know this is no problem in this simple example, but imagine the nesting that would be required if the stream would have multiple conditionals or simply continues before the `.test()`

Comment: If you are using Kotlin you could have used an extension function `ifTrue` to the `Completable` class. In java, may be you could write a wrapper class for this purpose, which will make the code more readable. This is just a suggestion, not sure will it completely suite your requirement. Please see the updated answer